# how exactly do I get my code to output the last number of even arguments?

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, command-line-arguments

Write a C program that accepts up to six arguments at the command line prompt. The program should
print the first character of any odd numbered arguments, and the last character of any even numbered
arguments. The characters printed should be separated by spaces. The program should inform the user
of the correct program usage if fewer than two or more than six arguments are provided. Assume each
argument contains at least two characters. For example

Should print this:

Given arguments: myprog arg1 200 list all arg5

Returns: m 1 2 t a 5

How would I get my code to list the arguments inputted by name as well as the last character of even numbered arguments?

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) 
{ 
    int counter;
    //here in c always one argument is ./a.out so we will check counting one extra
    //argc contains the number of argument passed 
    //argv contain all the arguments
    if(argc<3 || argc>7)
    {
        //invalid number of arguments
        printf("\nplease pass appropriate number of command line attributes");
    }
    else
    { 
        //printing all the arguments 

        printf("\nName of arguments passed: %s\n", argv[counter]); 

    //looping through all argumnets
        for(counter=0;counter<argc;counter++)
        {   //if is at even place but here odd as numbering from 1
            if(counter%-1==0){
                printf("%c ",argv[counter][0]);
            } 
            //odd place
            else
            {
                printf("%c ",argv[counter][0]);
            }
        }
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

my code is printing this:

name Of Arguments Passed: myprog

. m a 2 l a a

Comment: Change the line where you find the modulo, to counter % 2 == 0.  And also print the last character by finding the strlen() function of the argument.

Comment: @billyjoe2 Is the first user supplied argument odd?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes it is when it should be printing the first character of any of any odd numbered arguement s and the last character of even numbered arguement.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran would i add the #include<string.h> and then declare a string and then make the string the arguements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the function `strlen(<str>)` to calculate the length of the string to get the last letter (make sure to -1 from the result). The `strlen` function is from `<string.h>`

<strike>**Quick note 0:**

As you set `counter` to 0 in your for loop you actually include `a.out` as an argument (change it to `counter=1`) and change `(counter%-1==0)` to `(counter%2==1`)</strike>
*no longer relevant due to comment*

**Quick note 1:**
you can clean up your code by exiting if an invalid number of args is passed removing an indent level

```c
if(argc<3 || argc>7)
{
    //invalid number of arguments
    printf("\nplease pass appropriate number of command line attributes");
    return 1; // 1 means an error occured
}
// rest of code here
```

**Quick note 2:**
You declare `counter` but do not initialize it meaning `printf("\nName of arguments passed: %s\n", argv[counter]);` has undefined behaviour as `counter` could be anything. To fix this either change the declaration to `counter = 0` or change `argv[counter]` to `argv[0]`. Otherwise, the code will sometimes cause a segfault.

**Quick note 3 (sorry):**
'\n' should be placed at the end of print statements not at the beginning.
By placing them at the beginning you make the output very weirdly formatted

```bash
> ./a.out myprog arg1 200 list all arg5

Name of arguments passed: ./a.out
. m a 2 l a a  13 >
```

**Final code:**

```c
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h> 

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) 
{ 
    int counter = 0;
    //here in c always one argument is ./a.out so we will check counting one extra
    //argc contains the number of argument passed 
    //argv contain all the arguments
    if(argc<3 || argc>7)
    {
        //invalid number of arguments
        printf("please pass appropriate number of command line attributes\n"); // new line is added at the end
        return 1;
    }
    //printing all the arguments 
    printf("Name of arguments passed: ");
    for(counter=0;counter<argc;counter++) // loop through each argument and print it
    {
        printf(argv[counter]);
        putchar(' '); // put a space between each arg
    }
    putchar('\n'); // add new line to the end
    //looping through all argumnets
    for(counter=1;counter<argc;counter++)
    {   //if is at even place but here odd as numbering from 1
        if(counter%2==1){ // used to be (counter%-1==0)
            printf("%c ",argv[counter][0]);
        } 
        //odd place
        else
        {
            printf("%c ",argv[counter][strlen(argv[counter]) - 1]);
        }
    }
    putchar('\n'); // add new line to the end
    return 0; 
}
```

**Output**

```
> ./a.out
Name of arguments passed: ./a.out myprog arg1 200 list all arg5
m 1 2 t a 5
```

Comment: I will I just am not home rn but i’ll check it as soon as i get home!

Comment: it is not printing all the arguments, just the ./run how would I fix this to make it print all the arguments and not just the run argument?

Comment: If you want to print all the arguments you need to add a for loop similar to the one which prints the result. I'll add it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

This for loop

```
    for(counter=0;counter<argc;counter++)
    {   //if is at even place but here odd as numbering from 1
        if(counter%-1==0){
            printf("%c ",argv[counter][0]);
        } 
        //odd place
        else
        {
            printf("%c ",argv[counter][0]);
        }
    }
```

is incorrect at least because the initial value of the variable counter should be equal to 1. `argv[0]` is not a user supplied argument.

Also the condition in the if statement

```
if(counter%-1==0){
```

does not make a sense. It seems there is a typo.

The loop can look the following way

```
#include <string.h>

//...

for ( counter = 1; counter < argc; counter++ )
{
    if ( counter % 2 != 0 )
    {
        printf( "%c ", argv[counter][0] );
    } 
    else
    {
        printf( "%c ", argv[counter][strlen( argv[counter] ) - 1] );
    }
}
```

Though it will be safer to write the loop like

```
for ( counter = 1; counter < argc; counter++ )
{
    if ( *argv[counter] )
    {
        if ( counter % 2 != 0 )
        {
            printf( "%c ", argv[counter][0] );
        } 
        else
        {
            printf( "%c ", argv[counter][strlen( argv[counter] ) - 1] );
        }
    }
}
```

Because the user can specify an empty string "" as a command line  argument.

Comment: `counter%-1==0` actually does work for checking for `%2==0`. Although I do agree it is very unconventional & unreadable. This also doesn't give the correct answer (there are multiple errors in his original code)

Comment: I had to compile it myself to test (& stuff) and %-1==0 seems to work. I have absoltuley no idea why.

Comment: @SollyBunny It is equal to 0 for any number independent on whether the number is even or odd. So the expression does not make a sense.

Answer (score 0):

Too much code. To many places where things can go wrong.

The whole "even/odd" problem is a problem. Are you to number the arguments starting from 1 or from 0? The code below uses the OP's sample output for reference.

```
// myprog.c - an assignment

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    if( 2 <= argc && argc <= 6 ) // corresponds to problem statement
        ; // all good!
    else {
        // "The program should inform the user of the correct program usage"
        printf( "Number of arguments must be 2-6\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf( "Given arguments: ");
    for( int i = 0; i < argc; i++ )
        printf( "%s ", argv[ i ] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    for( ; argc; argc--, argv++ )
        printf( "%c ", argv[0][ (argc % 2) * (strlen(*argv) - 1) ] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

```
Given arguments: myprog arg1 200 list all arg5
m 1 2 t a 5
```

And, it seems that the other offered answers don't include the name of the program as an "argument" as shown in the OP's desired output... Hmmm... Is "myprog" the name of the executable executing? I presume it is, to make sense of the terms "arg1" and "arg5".